# How to split the string with bullets(All types)using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, split

Below is my text

```
 Welcome to java programming 1) Oops concepts a) Encapsulation A) Abstraction I) Inheritance  • Polymorphism
2)sample program on java 1.Project source code 
sample text files • sample.txt b)sam.txt
```

I want to split the text based on below pattern and remove the bullets

```
1)any bullet 1)I)a)A)•
2)followed by space
3)followed by uppercase word
```

So i want to generate following result

```
Welcome to java programming 
Oops concepts 
Encapsulation 
Abstraction
Inheritance  
Polymorphism
sample program on java
Project source code
Please suggest me how to do this
sample text files
sample.txt
```

sam.txt
Thanks

Comment: Do you also want to insert the periods after each item, or is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String s = "Welcome to java programming 1) Oops concepts a) Encapsulation A) Abstraction I) Inheritance  • Polymorphism";
    final String[] split = s.split("\\s*(\\w\\)|•)\\s*");
    for (final String bullet : split) {
        System.out.println(bullet);
    }
}
```

The regex is

```
\\s*(\\w\\)|•)\\s*
```

- `\\s*` - zero or more spaces
- `(\\w\\)|•)` - a digit or letter followed by a bracket or a bullet point
- `\\s*` - zero or more spaces

Output:

```
Welcome to java programming
Oops concepts
Encapsulation
Abstraction
Inheritance
Polymorphism
```

Comment: it is working for my above sentence, but its not working for other statements for ex: John provides CC cources 1. He also provides some other cources.  It include Company Inc.

Comment: `[\\d\\w]` is identical to just `\\w`, because word chars include digits

Comment: You Have a value like 1) Oops concepts, My question is if you have 11) or 110) instead of 1). What will be you Suggestion.

Comment: I don't have one. You could perhaps ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Following *positive lookahead* based regex should work for you:

```
String s = "Welcome to java programming 1) Oops concepts a) Encapsulation A) Abstraction I) Inheritance  • Polymorphism";
String[] arr = s.split("\\s*([a-zA-Z\\d][).]|•)\\s*(?=[A-Z])");
System.out.println("Split => " + Arrays.toString(tok));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Split => [Welcome to java programming, Oops concepts, Encapsulation, Abstraction, Inheritance, Polymorphism]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too

```
String str="Welcome to java programming 1) Oops concepts a) Encapsulation A) Abstraction I) Inheritance  • Polymorphism" ;
    String newStr=str.replaceAll("(?i)\\s*([\\d\\w]\\)|•)\\s*"," ISseperatorIS ");
    String[] arr=newStr.split("ISseperatorIS ");
    for(String i:arr){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Out put

```
Welcome to java programming 
Oops concepts 
Encapsulation 
Abstraction 
Inheritance 
Polymorphism
```

Comment: it is working for my above sentence, but its not working for other statements for ex: John provides CC cources 1. He also provides some other cources.  It include Company Inc. it should split for the statemenrs similar to this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Bullet {
public static void main(String [] args){
    String str = "Welcome to java programming 1) Oops concepts a) Encapsulation A) Abstraction I) Inheritance  • Polymorphism2)sample program on java 1.Project source code sample text files • sample.txt b)sam.txt";
    String [] bullet = str.split("[0-9]\\)|[A-Z]\\)|[a-z]\\)|•|[0-9]\\.");
    for(String i:bullet){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

}

Output<\p>

*Welcome to java programming
 
 Oops concepts 

 Encapsulation 

 Abstraction 

 Inheritance  

 Polymorphism

sample program on java
 
Project source code sample text files
 
 sample.txt 

sam.txt*